# Which file contains the includes for css and js files in magento?

Tags: magento

I am builidng website using magento. In magento, I see contents inside head (aka js, css etc) are rendered through php echo as in

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
```

I am curious, usually in which php/phtml/? file, does the reference for these css/js files stay? I see lots of css and html files getting included. HOwever, I can not seem to figure out from which file

Comment: there are various ways to add js,css files. check http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-external-javascript-css-file-to-magento/  and https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2013/10/24/adding-javascript-and-css-files-to-head-section-of-magento.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default css and JS are included from `page.xml` locatated at

```
app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\layout\page.xml
```

in this file you can see

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
```

............

```
 </block>
```

also custom js and css are included froma any xml file like

```
<reference name="head">
                <action method="addItem"><type>external_css</type><name>http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/build/reset/reset.css</name><params/></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>external_js</type><name>http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js</name><params/></action>
                <action method="addExternalItem"><type>external_js</type><name>http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/imageloader/imageloader-min.js</name><params/></action>
                <action method="addExternalItem"><type>external_css</type><name>http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/fonts/fonts-min.css</name><params/></action>
            </reference>
```

Let me know if you have any query